# .mousedown() event not triggering on JScrollPane when clicking on the dragbar

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, mousedown, mouseup

I am writing a code to snap the drag on the right place when the user drags them manually.

I'm trying to use the .onmousedown() event to get the dragbar position when the user mouses down on it and compare the position on the .onmouseup() event.

For the mousedown:

```
var dragBarPosBefore = 0;
$(document).mousedown(function () {   
  dragBarPosBefore = ($(".jspPane").position().left) * -1;;  
  console.log(dragBarPosBefore);
});
```

and now mouseup:

```
var dragBarPos = 0;
$(document).mouseup(function () {
     dragBarPos = ($(".jspPane").position().left) * -1; 
     console.log(dragBarPos);
});
```

And then I compare them. However, only the .mouseup() function is working when I click on the dragbar. the mousedown ONLY WORKS WHEN I CLICK ANYWHERE ELSE BESIDES THE DRAGBAR.

anyone know the reason and how to fix this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you do $(document).mousedown you are binding an event on the entire document. That's why the event triggers when you click somewhere else. Is that your intention?

Try:

```
$('#dragBar').mousedown(function ...)
```

Comment: Still not working.. and yes that's my intention for the mouseup only, because I need to get the position data even if the user releases the mouse button away from the dragBar.
But it isn't necessary for the mousedown, as it'll always start on the dragbar anyways.

Comment: a reminder: The problem only occurs when you mousedown on the DRAGBAR. The rest of the document is working fine. check the console

Comment: The initialiseHorizontalScroll function of the plugin hijacks the 'mousedown' on the drag element and returns false, which prevents your event to be triggered.

https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/blob/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js#L404

Comment: And since the only way to add an event to a dynamic created element is with $(document).on(event, element, function), I don't think this is possible with this plugin...

Comment: I think that if I use event.preventDefault() it will work, but I don't know how to use it.